# Find closest <a> link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following list:-

```
    <div id="main-links-bottom-hover">

        <div id="About" class="hovers">

            <div id="main-about-div">

                <li class="lnk1 about-lnk"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="lnk2 about-lnk"><a href="technology.php">Technology</a></li>
                <li class="lnk3 about-lnk"><a href="environment.php">Environment</a></li>
                <li class="lnk4 about-lnk"><a href="terms.php">T&amp;C's</a></li>
                <li class="lnk5 about-lnk"><a href="pricing.php">Pricing Policy</a></li>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

For each `<li>` I want to set the li to open the closest `<a href>`.

I have tried:-

```
    $('li').each(function(){
        var linkitem = $('.lnk1 a', this).attr('href');
        $('a.lnk1', this).attr('href' , linkitem) 
    });
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, any suggestions?

ADDED CSS:-

```
#main-about-div {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}

.lnk1, .lnk2, .lnk3, .lnk4, .lnk5, .lnk6 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #1f5779;
}

.lnk1 a {
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.lnk2 a {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.lnk3 a {
    position:absolute;
    top:61px;
    left:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.lnk4 a {
    position:absolute;
    top:92px;
    left:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.lnk5 a {
    position:absolute;
    top:124px;
    left:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.lnk6 a {
    position:absolute;
    top:156px;
    left:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear for me what are you trying to do

Comment: What do you mean by closest?  Nested?

Comment: Are you saying that when you click on the li you want it to open the nearest href?

Comment: @LeeTaylor i understand it like you which of course doesn't make sense

Comment: Basically, I want it so if you click the first li (.lnk1) it will look at the nearest a href, and open contact.php, and same for each other li item

Comment: <<<Long text explaining that I don't understand exactly what you need>>> but... children[0] (for your structure)?

Comment: @nsilva you don't need that, you are already clicking on the anchor. Or you didn't post all your relevant code

Comment: Aside from whether the selectors actually work, this appears to be trying to set the `href` property of your anchors to what it is already set to. Why?

Comment: Well say the li has a width of say 300px, I have to actually click the text so open the link, where as I want to be able to click anywhere on the li item to be able to open the link

Comment: you could also just put the urls on the `li` tags themselves, such as in `data-href`, then load the url when one is clicked.

Comment: Following EDIT: You are using some style rules which make anchor tag  setted with display:block; not able to take all the space as position:absolute of anchor and margins of LI

Comment: BTW, LI must be nested inside an UL/OL element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this:

```
#main-about-div a {
    display: block
}
```

Since your LI elements only contain one A element each, if you make the A elements block-level, they should take up the entire space of their parent LI element, and then clicking on the LI element will automatically mean that the corresponding A element is also clicked.

---

**Update:** After seeing your CSS code.

```
#main-about-div li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:13px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #1f5779;
}
#main-about-div a {
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;
    background: pink;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/reSE8/ (uses [normalized CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/))

Notice how the A elements are blocks now and the dimensions are set on them instead of the LI elements.

Comment: far better than using a javascript hack.

Comment: @sgroves except if LI not only contains an anchor tag

Comment: @roasted of course. if they contained something other than an `a` tag, OP would have no reason to want to do this. there is no good reason to use javascript for this.

Comment: @sgroves <<if they contained something other than an a tag, OP would have no reason to want to do this>> How do you know that? What if LI contains a label too? Could be a good reason, no?

Comment: For sure if OP is nesting only anchor tag inside LI, this solution is better!

Comment: @roasted There's no "if". OP provided the HTML.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas he should have provided CSS too because obviously OP didn't need to ask a question then using only code he provided. BTW, what if is using pseudo class as :before or :after?

Comment: @roasted Instead of us arguing the scenarios in which this solution might and might not work, OP should just try the code and report back.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas ya, sure, i'm agree!

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I've tried this but this did not resolve the problem. By adding this it had no effect, I still had to click the text to open the link.

Comment: @nsilva you should provide then relevant CSS code to your question or a live sample

Comment: @nsilva Why are you manually positioning each A element? Don't do that. I've updated my answer with working code.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas nice one even LI should be inside an ul/ol or menu ;)

Answer (score -1):

This may help!

> $('li').each(function(){
>
> ```
>     p = $(this).find('a');
>     $(p).attr('href','Not sure what you are trying to do but your custom href goes here');
>     
> });
> ```